# Is $f $ decreasing?

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty) $, $f (x)+f (y)\geq 2f (x+y), \forall x, y>0$.

Is $f $ decreasing?

I need to show that $f (x)+f (y)+f (z)\geq 3f (x+y+z) $ and it's enough to show that $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown It's not a counterexample because in that case $x+y $ should be smaller then $0$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown If $f (x)= x $ then  $x+y\geq 2x+2y $. So $ x+y\leq 0$. But $x, y>0$

Comment: Note that the constant function satisfies the first inequality, and it is not decreasing.

Comment: @Niki Di Giano the constant function is in standard terminology decreasing but it is not strictly decreasing

Comment: Then decreasing is the same as what I've been calling nonincreasing, in standard terminology. With this specification, I've got nothing else to say about the problem for the time being.

Comment: Your guess that $f$ is decreasing is wrong. Consider $x \mapsto x+1/x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to prove your property.

Note that $4f(x+y+z)\le2f(x)+2f(y+z)\le2f(x)+f(y)+f(z)$.

By symmetry $4f(x+y+z)\le2f(y)+f(x)+f(z)$ and $4f(x+y+z)\le2f(z)+f(x)+f(y)$.

Summing up the inequalities give $12f(x+y+z)\le4f(x)+4f(y)+4f(z)$,
dividing by four gives $3f(x+y+z)\le f(x)+f(y)+f(z).$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 2f(x+y)+f(z) = f(x+y) +f(z) + f(x+y)+f(z)-f(z) \ge 2f(x+y+z)+2f(x+y+z)-f(z)=4f(x+y+z)-f(z)$$

In the same manner:
$$f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 2f(x+z)+f(y) = f(x+z) +f(y) + f(x+z)+f(y)-f(y) \ge 2f(x+y+z)+2f(x+y+z)-f(y)=4f(x+y+z)-f(y)$$
And:
$$f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 2f(y+z)+f(x) = f(y+z) +f(x) + f(y+z)+f(x)-f(x) \ge 2f(x+y+z)+2f(x+y+z)-f(x)=4f(x+y+z)-f(x)  $$

In the end we have:
$$ f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 4f(x+y+z)-f(z)$$
$$ f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 4f(x+y+z)-f(y)$$
$$ f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 4f(x+y+z)-f(x)$$

Summing the we get:
$$3(f(x)+f(y)+f(z)) \ge 12f(x+y+z)-f(x)-f(y)-f(z) \Leftrightarrow 4(f(x)+f(y)+f(z)) \ge 12f(x+y+z) \Leftrightarrow f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 3f(x+y+z)$$

I wish I helped!